# Waiting for keypress in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

**Problem**

I am writing code for a simple stopwatch. In that after every three runs the frame is cleared and a new session is started in the same window. The times are written to a file. But before clearing the screen I want the user to have a look at the time taken and then clear the screen.

**Goal**

Wait for a keypress so that we can destroy the frame and print some new text after that.

**What I checked**

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216830/tkinter-keypress-event-python

This was not very helpful because the key was being printed.

**conditions**

I don't care what the key is unless it is some of the following things:

`['e','s','r']`

If the key pressed is not on of these then I can go ahead and clear the screen. These keys are being used for some other specific purposes in the program.

**Please** help me with a way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to bind an event handler on `"<Key>"`.

```
def handler(event):
    if event.char in ('e','s','r'):
       return #Don't want to handle this keypress
    #code to clear-screen, etc.

your_frame.bind('<Key>',handler)
```

Depending on your application, you may choose instead to use:

```
your_frame.bind_all('<Key>',handler)
```

[reference](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/events-and-bindings.htm)